# WCF REST - how to read Stream to text

Tags: wcf, rest, stream

I have a WCF REST Service. The XML body of each incoming message is deserialized into my objects as follows:

```
            private static Message MyMethod(Stream stream)
            {
                try
                {
                    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyObject));
                    var myObject = (MyObject)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
                    //do stuff
                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException invEx)
                {
                    //write stream (xml) to error log
                }
                //etc

            }
```

I would like to be able to write the XML to log when the Deserialization fails.  Everything I have tried results in an Empty String.  Is this even possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could easily bring the whole thing in as a `string` rather than a `Stream`, and load/deserialize from that. Is there a particular reason for the `Stream`?

Alternatively (better, IMO), you can specify the object you want de-serialized as a `DataContract` and require XML in your operation contract and let the WCF framework do the work *for* you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to reposition the stream before writing to the error log?

stream.Position = 0;